# Ошибка "string index out of range". Что не так с кодом?

Tags: python

Собственно, вод неработающий код. (Цель - подсчитать среднее арифметическое.) Что с ним не так?

```
a = input()
n = len(a)
i = 0
sum = 0
while i < n:
  i = i + 1
  sum = int(a[i])
mean = sum / n
```

Comment: Кстати, для Вашей задачи есть функция из стандартной библиотеки: [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).

Answer (score 1):

Инкрементировать счётчик `i` нужно в конце цикла. Также Вы неправильно подсчитываете сумму — переопределяете её на каждой итерации.

***Пример:***

```py
while i < n:
    sum = sum + int(a[i])  # sum += int(a[i])
    i = i + 1              # i += 1
```

**P. S.:**
В `Python` есть функция `sum`, которую Вы переопределяете. Лучше назвать переменную по-другому.

Comment: Простите, а как сделать так, чтобы при подсчёте среднего арифметического не учитывались двойки?

Comment: @平秀明 Добавьте условие: `if int(a[i]) != 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Индексы начинаются с 0 и заканчиваются на len(a)-1.   Поэтому элемента a[i]  не существует. Поменяй местами обе строчки в цикле.